# AltBeacon detection in different Android app's states

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I have the following uses-case.
I have an Android application which may be in different states:

- Foreground (user is using the app);
- Background (user is not using the app but it's app's task exists and user can open the app form TaskManager any-time);
- Killed (app is killed and not available in TaskManager)

I need to detect a BLE beacon for all of these states and for now just show a notification.
I started with [this AltBeacon library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) and it covers **Foreground** and **Background** BLE beacon detection scenarios.
Library set up is straight-forward.

**BeaconManager setup:**

```
private lateinit var beaconManager: BeaconManager
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
```

**Prepare Beacon configuration:**

```
private fun prepareBeaconConfigurations() {
        BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).setIntentScanningStrategyEnabled(true)
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.clear()
        val iBeaconLayout = "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"
        val altBeaconLayout = "m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"
        val iBeaconParser = BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(iBeaconLayout)
        val altBeaconParser = BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(altBeaconLayout)
        iBeaconParser.setHardwareAssistManufacturerCodes(arrayOf(0x004c).toIntArray())
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(iBeaconParser)
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(altBeaconParser)
}
```

**Create Ranging and Monitoring observers:**

```
private val centralRangingObserver = Observer<Collection<Beacon>> { beacons ->
        val rangeAgeMillis =
            System.currentTimeMillis() - (beacons.firstOrNull()?.lastCycleDetectionTimestamp ?: 0)
        if (rangeAgeMillis < 10000) {
            logger.logD(TAG, "Ranged: ${beacons.count()} beacons")
            for (beacon: Beacon in beacons) {
                logger.logD(TAG, "$beacon about ${beacon.distance} meters away")
            }
        } else {
            logger.logD(TAG, "Ignoring stale ranged beacons from $rangeAgeMillis millis ago")
        }
    }

    private val centralMonitoringObserver = Observer<Int> { state ->
        if (state == MonitorNotifier.OUTSIDE) {
            logger.logD(TAG, "Outside beacon region: $region")
            sendNotification("A beacon connection is left.")
            Toast.makeText(this, "A beacon connection is left.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            logger.logD(TAG, "Inside beacon region: $region")
            sendNotification("A beacon is nearby.")
            Toast.makeText(this, "A beacon is nearby.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }
```

And final step start monitoring (when all required conditions like permissions, bluetooth ON e.t.c are met)

```
private fun initBeaconObserver() {
     beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)
     beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)

     val regionViewModel =
         BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).getRegionViewModel(region)

     regionViewModel.regionState.observeForever(centralMonitoringObserver)
     regionViewModel.rangedBeacons.observeForever(centralRangingObserver)
 }
```

Having this config set up:

```
BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).setIntentScanningStrategyEnabled(true)
```

Solved the problem to detect BLE beacons when app is killed but it's not reliable. It was working a few times when I initially added this config but now it stopped working and I wonder why.

I'm looking for any advices that may help me with my use-case. Maybe exist other approaches to detect BLE beacons. The one I chose requires "All the tome location permission" and I can not be sure that user granted this important permission.

**Additional details for troubleshooting:**
Android OS - Android 14
Device - Pixel 7

**The steps for failed scenario**

1. Launch the app with the lib's configuration I left above.
2. See the message that beacon is detected.
3. Turn beacon off and on and see message is updated accordingly to beacon's status
4. Kill the app and try the same steps (turn on and off the beacon) OR just go outside of beacon's range and nothing happens.

**ADB logs:**

```
2023-10-11 17:12:48.344 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2023-10-11 17:12:48.390 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
2023-10-11 17:12:48.391 17290-17290 JobInfo                 com.testble.mobile                   W  Requested interval +5m10s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
2023-10-11 17:12:48.391 17290-17290 JobInfo                 com.testble.mobile                   W  Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
2023-10-11 17:12:48.460 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  ScanJob Lifecycle START: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@38e0c55
2023-10-11 17:12:48.610 17290-17364 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   D  BeaconParsers set to  count: 2
2023-10-11 17:12:48.610 17290-17364 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   D  First parser layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
2023-10-11 17:12:48.610 17290-17364 CycledLeScanner         com.testble.mobile                   I  Using Android O scanner
2023-10-11 17:12:48.618 17290-17364 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2023-10-11 17:12:48.619 17290-17364 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@38e0c55
2023-10-11 17:12:48.625 17290-17364 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  scanJob version 2.20-beta1 is starting up on the main process
2023-10-11 17:12:48.632 17290-17367 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   I  Non-distinct packets detected in a single scan.  Restarting scans unecessary.
2023-10-11 17:12:48.667 17290-17364 ModelSpeci...Calculator com.testble.mobile                   W  Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2023-10-11 17:12:48.669 17290-17364 ModelSpeci...Calculator com.testble.mobile                   W  Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2023-10-11 17:12:48.675 17290-17364 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:12:48.705 17290-17365 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:12:48.707 17290-17364 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Scan job running for 10000 millis
2023-10-11 17:12:48.712 17290-17305 BluetoothLeScanner      com.testble.mobile                   D  onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=3 mScannerId=0
2023-10-11 17:12:58.711 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Scan job runtime expired: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@38e0c55
2023-10-11 17:12:58.727 17290-17290 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:12:58.747 17290-17365 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:12:58.890 17290-17290 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:12:59.157 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2023-10-11 17:12:59.190 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
2023-10-11 17:12:59.190 17290-17290 JobInfo                 com.testble.mobile                   W  Requested interval +5m10s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
2023-10-11 17:12:59.191 17290-17290 JobInfo                 com.testble.mobile                   W  Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
2023-10-11 17:12:59.231 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  ScanJob Lifecycle START: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@2147653
2023-10-11 17:12:59.461 17290-17376 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   D  BeaconParsers set to  count: 2
2023-10-11 17:12:59.461 17290-17376 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   D  First parser layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
2023-10-11 17:12:59.461 17290-17376 CycledLeScanner         com.testble.mobile                   I  Using Android O scanner
2023-10-11 17:12:59.471 17290-17376 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2023-10-11 17:12:59.472 17290-17376 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@2147653
2023-10-11 17:12:59.478 17290-17376 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  scanJob version 2.20-beta1 is starting up on the main process
2023-10-11 17:12:59.507 17290-17376 ModelSpeci...Calculator com.testble.mobile                   W  Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2023-10-11 17:12:59.508 17290-17376 ModelSpeci...Calculator com.testble.mobile                   W  Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2023-10-11 17:12:59.512 17290-17376 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:12:59.540 17290-17377 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:12:59.541 17290-17376 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Scan job running for 10000 millis
2023-10-11 17:12:59.548 17290-17305 BluetoothLeScanner      com.testble.mobile                   D  onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=3 mScannerId=0
2023-10-11 17:12:59.673 17290-17386 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   I  Non-distinct packets detected in a single scan.  Restarting scans unecessary.
2023-10-11 17:13:09.544 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Scan job runtime expired: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@2147653
2023-10-11 17:13:09.559 17290-17290 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:09.575 17290-17377 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:09.747 17290-17290 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:10.202 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2023-10-11 17:13:10.231 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
2023-10-11 17:13:10.231 17290-17290 JobInfo                 com.testble.mobile                   W  Requested interval +5m10s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
2023-10-11 17:13:10.232 17290-17290 JobInfo                 com.testble.mobile                   W  Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
2023-10-11 17:13:10.251 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  ScanJob Lifecycle START: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@bffaf41
2023-10-11 17:13:10.381 17290-17389 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   D  BeaconParsers set to  count: 2
2023-10-11 17:13:10.381 17290-17389 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   D  First parser layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
2023-10-11 17:13:10.381 17290-17389 CycledLeScanner         com.testble.mobile                   I  Using Android O scanner
2023-10-11 17:13:10.390 17290-17389 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2023-10-11 17:13:10.390 17290-17389 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@bffaf41
2023-10-11 17:13:10.395 17290-17389 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  scanJob version 2.20-beta1 is starting up on the main process
2023-10-11 17:13:10.405 17290-17391 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   I  Non-distinct packets detected in a single scan.  Restarting scans unecessary.
2023-10-11 17:13:10.425 17290-17389 ModelSpeci...Calculator com.testble.mobile                   W  Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2023-10-11 17:13:10.426 17290-17389 ModelSpeci...Calculator com.testble.mobile                   W  Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2023-10-11 17:13:10.433 17290-17389 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:10.466 17290-17390 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:10.466 17290-17389 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Scan job running for 10000 millis
2023-10-11 17:13:10.472 17290-17304 BluetoothLeScanner      com.testble.mobile                   D  onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=3 mScannerId=0
2023-10-11 17:13:20.471 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Scan job runtime expired: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@bffaf41
2023-10-11 17:13:20.483 17290-17290 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:20.501 17290-17390 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:20.635 17290-17290 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:21.591 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2023-10-11 17:13:21.638 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
2023-10-11 17:13:21.639 17290-17290 JobInfo                 com.testble.mobile                   W  Requested interval +5m10s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
2023-10-11 17:13:21.639 17290-17290 JobInfo                 com.testble.mobile                   W  Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
2023-10-11 17:13:21.687 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  ScanJob Lifecycle START: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@d01a69f
2023-10-11 17:13:21.898 17290-17401 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   D  BeaconParsers set to  count: 2
2023-10-11 17:13:21.898 17290-17401 ScanHelper              com.testble.mobile                   D  First parser layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
2023-10-11 17:13:21.898 17290-17401 CycledLeScanner         com.testble.mobile                   I  Using Android O scanner
2023-10-11 17:13:21.909 17290-17401 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2023-10-11 17:13:21.910 17290-17401 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@d01a69f
2023-10-11 17:13:21.915 17290-17401 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  scanJob version 2.20-beta1 is starting up on the main process
2023-10-11 17:13:21.948 17290-17401 ModelSpeci...Calculator com.testble.mobile                   W  Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2023-10-11 17:13:21.949 17290-17401 ModelSpeci...Calculator com.testble.mobile                   W  Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2023-10-11 17:13:21.955 17290-17401 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:21.991 17290-17401 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Scan job running for 10000 millis
2023-10-11 17:13:21.992 17290-17402 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:21.997  9012-9032  BtGatt.GattService      com.google.android.bluetooth         E  App 'com.testble.mobile' is scanning too frequently
2023-10-11 17:13:21.999 17290-17400 BluetoothLeScanner      com.testble.mobile                   D  onScannerRegistered() - status=6 scannerId=-1 mScannerId=0
2023-10-11 17:13:31.995 17290-17290 ScanJob                 com.testble.mobile                   I  Scan job runtime expired: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@d01a69f
2023-10-11 17:13:32.014 17290-17290 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:32.032 17290-17402 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
2023-10-11 17:13:32.033 17290-17402 BluetoothLeScanner      com.testble.mobile                   D  could not find callback wrapper
2023-10-11 17:13:32.169 17290-17290 BluetoothAdapter        com.testble.mobile                   D  isLeEnabled(): ON
```

Comment: You say "it's not reliable. It was working a few times when I initially added this config but now it stopped working and I wonder why."  This is a complex issue, and we need very precise descriptions of the failure test cases to help.  What device model and OS version are you using?   Are you turning your beacon on and off, or are you moving the phone out of range.  If out for range, how far?   What are the precise test steps you use to reproduce (repeatedly) the failure case?  Is the app running in a failure case?  (Check with `add shell ps`). How does Logical look different when it fails?

Comment: Hi @davidgyoung. I've updated question's descriptions with detailed steps and ADB logs.

Comment: Please read the expected detection times on the documentation page [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection_times.html) especially the section for the Intent Scan Strategy.  It is important to realize that the IntentScanStrategy is very good for fast detections of beacons appearing,  but very slow to tell you that beacons have disappeared.   In documenting your test case, it is very important to say what the beacon detection state was before you killed the app -- both whether the beacon is on or off, and how long it had been in that state before you killed the app.

Comment: Thanks for the hints @davidgyoung. Does IntentScanStrategy work only when ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION is granted?

Comment: Yes, it requires background location permission.